# Need to set up shared storage for Guest virtual machines that are running on a Xen host

Tags: virtualization, nfs, xen, nas, iscsi

**My environment:**
I am doing these things at home with the purpose of learning about virtualization techniques. My machine have quad core processor that supports Intel-VT and 8GB RAM. XEN is the virtualization platform. In short, all domUs are LVM based.

Mainly I have two questions;

1. I need to have **shared storage** for these VMs. Something like NFS / NAS / iSCSI etc. However, I don't know which one is the best solution. **Therefore, can someone tell me which suits best?** Please  note that, this **shared storage** need to be accessed by the other physical machines in the network.
2. How to implement the selected solution for question #1? Any tutorials / guidelines / ebooks will be a great help and highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

For #1 Best is very subjective in the space. Best in terms of cost, performance, easy to use, setup, etc. can vary a lot.

For #2, some good references here: http://runningxen.com/resources/index.html#chapter8. The Running Xen book is a great resource in general (I am a co-author).

Also, I think that this is a better question for Server Fault ( https://serverfault.com/) and/or the Xen users list( http://lists.xen.org/mailman/listinfo/xen-users). I bet it has been discussed thoroughly on the xen-users list actually. Search here: http://xen.markmail.org/